# Scrape only x amount of characters - how?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

**BACKGROUND**

I own a website that indexes all psychologists of Denmark. 
My site provides contact information for all the clinics as well as user ratings.

I'm currently listing 12.000 Psychologists, of which about 6.000 have a website. About 1000 of the Psychologists have visited my website, and filled out their profile with additional "Descriptive" info (such as opening hours, prices, etc.)

I'm attempting to automatically scrape (with PHP and RegEx) the sites of those who haven't provided details to my community, for informative reasons.

I went through about a good random 150 of the websites, and concluded that more than 85 % af them, have valuable text proceeding the word 'Velkommen' (=welcome, in Denish). PRECIOUS!

**THE QUESTIONS**

**#1**

How do I specificy in my script, that I'd only like to grab approx. 360 characters, and nothing more. Ofc. this should be preceeding (and including) the word Velkommen. Also, the script shouldn't be case sensitive (though Velkommen is usually spelled with a capital V, it can pop up in another sentence.)

Also, it should the last occuring 'velkommen' on the whole frontpage, since it sometimes occurs as a Menu/Navigation option, which would suck, since i'd then grab the navigation options.

**#2**

Currently - my script saves info in arrays, and then in the database.

Not sure how I should even go about this. What would be optimal for SEO;

1. Save the scraped text in a MySQL and display that every time.
2. Render the same 360-characters-text every time [that follows 'Velkommen']
3. Render random 360-characters-text from the sites, each time someone views a specific Psychologist on my site.

An example site:

```
$web = "http://www.psykologdorthelau.dk/";
$website = file_get_contents ($web);

preg_match_all("/velkommen.+?/sim", $website, $information);

//THIS SHOULD SPECIFICY THE VERY LAST 'VELKOMMEN' - it doesn't, I know :(
for($i = 0; $i < count($information[0]); $i++){

preg_match_all("/Velkommen (.+?)\"/sim", $information[0][$i], $text, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$psychologist[$i]['text'] = mysql_real_escape_string($text[0][1]);
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can solve this puzzle, from the wonderful country of Denmark.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to fetch only a certain amount of data you can use a filestream.

It would look something like this:

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r"); // open a filestream
// Fetch for example only 10 bytes each time we check
$chunkSize = 10;
$contents = "";
while ( !feof( $handle ) && strlen($contents) < 360) { 
    $buffer = fread( $handle, $chunkSize ); 

    $contents .= $buffer;

} 
$status = fclose( $handle ); 

//your data is stored in $contents
```

Comment: But this doesnt specifify that the scraped data should be preceeding the word 'velkommen'

Comment: You can fill in the rest with some basic PHP knowledge; strcontains('velkommen') for example... Do you want someone to code the whole thing for you, or are you just asking a question to figure things out yourself? This is not a 'hire a programmer' website...

Answer (score 1):

"the scraped data should be preceeding the word 'velkommen'":

```
preg_replace_callback('/velkommen(.*){360}/i',
  function($matched) {
    // Use $matched[1] to perform further testing
  },
  $contents
);
```

It's hacky, but it will get you started. Requires PHP 5.4 I believe.